# Can I save a file which will be generated from php code on server side using only javascript/C/C++ and no browser opened?

Tags: javascript, c++, c, url, download

What is the best way to save a file from internet on **javascript** and/or **C** and/or even **C++**?

I saw this same question for C# and Java, but nothing to this three languages, so here is the question.

Hey, not so easy. The url point to some http://xx.xxxx.com/p.php?pid=staticetctectc....

I guess is php code which produce a nice gif in my browser. I just want to save this gif. Without opening browser. It is possible to do with javascript/C/C++?

Most near answer I found is [this](https://superuser.com/questions/11099/how-to-download-a-url-as-a-file).

Thanks in any advice.

Comment: You certainly need HTTP, which you can run in a stack without a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do this with JavaScript using Node.js. Here is a link to an example: http://www.hacksparrow.com/using-node-js-to-download-files.html

You could also do it from the command line using wget or curl. They are both available on pretty much every platform you can imagine.

Comment: curl got me the most strange results I ever got... But wget made the show ... just using quotes to hold url. duuh. =) Thanks

Comment: curl can function just like wget, but you have to tell it to save the output to a file otherwise it sends it to the screen. That is why it looked so odd. That was the contents of the gif file on your screen. The command to save to a file with curl is `curl http://mywebsites.com/folder/file.gif -o file.gif`

Answer (score 2):

For C++, you could do it like in [Downloading File in Qt From URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383864/downloading-file-in-qt-from-url). If you do not want to depend on Qt, [libcurl](http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/) is also an option.

For JavaScript, the method described in [File Download Using JavaScript](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55488/File-Download-Using-JavaScript) should work.